# Absolute value of the difference between two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

Consider two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ both contained in $\mathbb{R}$ and assume that these two sequences satisfy $|a_n - b_n| \rightarrow 0$, then this does imply that both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent sequences? Or is it possible to have two divergent sequences but the absolute value of their difference forms a convergent sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(a_n)=(b_n)=(1,-1,1,-1,...)$.

Answer (score 0):

Even more:
if $(|a_n - b_n| \rightarrow 0)$ then ($a_n$ converges iff $b_n$ converges).

Comment: So in words: if $|a_n - b_n| \rightarrow 0$ is satisfied, then either both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent or both are divergent?

Comment: Right! Because $|a_n - b_n| \rightarrow 0$ iff $a_n - b_n \rightarrow 0$ (only valid for zero!).